# How do I manually add Pods/Headers/Public to the Header Search Paths configuration?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, expo

- I ejected from expo.
- I ran ‘react-native link’ in the terminal
- I moved into the iOS folder and ran ‘pod install’ in the terminal.
- Then I opened the padel.xcworkspace in xcode. When I try and build the app
  I get an error that says the React/RCTBridgeModule.h file is not
  found.
- After much googling I understand that I need to “manually add
  Pods/Headers/Public to the Header Search Paths configuration” as
  described in the expo docs
  https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/expokit.html#changing-native-dependencies

I have absolutely no idea how to do this. Can someone please help me?
When I click on the error message in build time this is what I see:
[image]

Where am I supposed to add ‘Pods/Headers/Public’

My best guess is that I have to add an additional path in the ‘Header Search Paths’ section. The problem is that I don’t understand where BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR corresponds to so I don’t know how to walk it to the pods folder.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer to this on step 3 of the docs on manual linking in react native https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#manual-linking